# Rollup a table eliminating null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I'm pretty sure this should be easy, I just don't know what function or whatever I need to get it done. I've got a table that has the number of hours worked in a day, # of documents reviewed, and the date they were reviewed.

I've been able to combine and pivot this out into a nice report of the person and the # of hours or docs. However, it's got null values throughout.

```
First   Last    11/30/2013  12/1/2013   12/2/2013
John    Doe     11           NULL           NULL
John    Doe     NULL           12           NULL
John    Doe     NULL            NULL            8
John    Doe     NULL            NULL            NULL
```

I need it to look like this

```
FirstName   LastName    11/30/2013  12/1/2013   12/2/2013
John        Doe             11          12      8
Jane        Smith             13        5       8
```

Figured it out, why it took me so long... I'm going to blame it on it being late...

```
Select Employee_ID 
,SUM(#Temp3.[1])
,SUM(#Temp3.[2])
,SUM(#Temp3.[4])
,SUM(#Temp3.[5])
,SUM(#Temp3.[6])
,SUM(#Temp3.[7])
From #Temp3
Group By Employee_ID
```

Comment: Well, I figured it out minutes after posting this...

Comment: Post your solution to help future users with similar problems.  Good job!